# How can I resolve type of expression is ambiguous error?

Tags: swift, firebase

In this block of code, the 
"                let remoteUser = try User(record: postDict, context: DatabaseManager.shared.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext())
"
line generates a type of error is ambiguous without more context error.

I am a little unsure why this error is generated -- however, I do know that I have two user objects -- a firebase User class, and a User class local to my application. When I specify the User as my modulename.User, the same error is raised. When I remove this user logic, the application builds correctly.

```
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailAddress, password: password) { (user, error) in
        // If Successful, pull firstName/lastName
        let ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(emailAddress)

        ref!.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let postDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary ?? [:]
            let firstName = postDict["firstName"] as? String ?? ""
            let lastName = postDict["lastName"] as? String ?? ""
            let showroom = postDict["showroom"] as! NSDictionary
            let showroomReference = showroom["showroomID"] as? String ?? ""

            if showroomReference == "" {
                completionHandler(.failure(Error.unknownShowroom))
            }

            let remoteUser = try User(record: postDict, context: DatabaseManager.shared.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext())

            self.fetchShowroom(forIdentifier: showroomReference) { (result) in
                do
                {
                    let showroom = try result.value()
                    remoteUser.showroom = showroom
                    remoteUser.brands = showroom.brands

                    completionHandler(.success(remoteUser))
                }
                catch
                {
                    completionHandler(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

I'd appreciate any help - thanks! XCode does not build unless I resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is a bit misleading. The `do - catch` block around the `try` statement is missing.

```
do {
   let remoteUser = try User(record: postDict, context: DatabaseManager.shared.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
   self.fetchShowroom(forIdentifier: showroomReference) { (result) in
      do {
         let showroom = try result.value()
         remoteUser.showroom = showroom
         remoteUser.brands = showroom.brands
         completionHandler(.success(remoteUser))
      } catch {
         completionHandler(.failure(error))
      }
  }
} catch {
   completionHandler(.failure(error))
}
```

Comment: Awesome this worked - thanks so much! Could you describe in more detail your methodology for resolving this?

Comment: I just read the code and noticed the `try` without the `do - catch` block